# Magento 2: How to Copy/Move "top.links" to "header-wrapper"

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the top.links to the header-wrapper as in the picture in order to create some fancy icons instead of just text links.

I was able to do that adding this line to the default.xml file on my custom theme.

```
<move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper"/>
```

But when i do that, top.links disappear from the interactive hamburger and gets added to the central page, and i don't want that.

I was thinking that instead of moving/copying the block and then hide it in the mobile version with CSS.

How can I clone that block in there?

[image: Moving the Block]

[image: Block Moved in mobile Version]

[image: Empty]

[image: Block moved in desktop]

Comment: Can you show how exactly you want to display ?